# How do I select just a subset of Terraform Outputs from the following structure

Tags: terraform

I am using Terraform with the following output.

```json
ip_addresses = [
  {
    "northcentralus" = {
      "allocation_method" = "Dynamic"
      "ddos_protection_mode" = "VirtualNetworkInherited"
      "ddos_protection_plan_id" = tostring(null)
      "domain_name_label" = ""
      "fqdn" = ""
      "id" = "/subscriptions/SUBID/resourceGroups/multisqlite-bacalhau-example-northcentralus-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/multisqlite-bacalhau-example-northcentralus-public-ip"
      "idle_timeout_in_minutes" = 4
      "ip_address" = "1.2.3.4"
      "ip_tags" = tomap({})
      "ip_version" = "IPv4"
      "location" = "northcentralus"
      "name" = "multisqlite-bacalhau-example-northcentralus-public-ip"
      "resource_group_name" = "multisqlite-bacalhau-example-northcentralus-rg"
      "reverse_fqdn" = ""
      "sku" = "Basic"
      "tags" = tomap({})
      "timeouts" = null /* object */
      "zones" = tolist([])
    }
    "southafricanorth" = {
      "allocation_method" = "Dynamic"
      "ddos_protection_mode" = "VirtualNetworkInherited"
      "ddos_protection_plan_id" = tostring(null)
      "domain_name_label" = ""
      "fqdn" = ""
      "id" = "/subscriptions/SUBID/resourceGroups/multisqlite-bacalhau-example-southafricanorth-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/publicIPAddresses/multisqlite-bacalhau-example-southafricanorth-public-ip"
      "idle_timeout_in_minutes" = 4
      "ip_address" = "1.2.3.5"
      "ip_tags" = tomap({})
      "ip_version" = "IPv4"
      "location" = "southafricanorth"
      "name" = "multisqlite-bacalhau-example-southafricanorth-public-ip"
      "resource_group_name" = "multisqlite-bacalhau-example-southafricanorth-rg"
      "reverse_fqdn" = ""
      "sku" = "Basic"
      "tags" = tomap({})
      "timeouts" = null /* object */
      "zones" = tolist([])
    }
  },
]
```

Ideally, I'd love just to get a subset of this information - specifically the `ip_address`. This is what my current `outputs.tf` looks like.

```
output "ip_addresses" {
  value = data.azurerm_public_ip.public_ip.*
}
```

But when I try the following, I get errors:

```
output "ip_addresses" {
  value = data.azurerm_public_ip.public_ip[*].ip_address
}
```

What's the right solution here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although not shown in the question I will assume based on the information in the question that the `data` contains a `for_each` meta-parameter with a `map` type where the keys are the two keys displayed in the example output for the `list(map)`. Given that assumption, one can assemble the ip addresses with a `for` expression in the `output` `value`:

```
output "ip_addresses" {
  value = { for region, attributes in data.azurerm_public_ip.public_ip : region => attributes.ip_address }
}
```

The resulting map in the `output` would appear as:

```
{
  "northcentralus"   = "1.2.3.4",
  "southafricanorth" = "1.2.3.5"
}
```

which is my best inference about the desired resultant structure based on the question. If instead you are looking for a `list(string)` of the ip addresses:

```
value = [ for region, attributes in data.azurerm_public_ip.public_ip : attributes.ip_address ]
# ["1.2.3.4", "1.2.3.5"]
```

If the desired transformation is something other than these, then hopefully it should still be clear from the two solutions provided.

Comment: terrific, thank you!